# GCM Push Notification without using JSON

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to migrate my application from C2DM service to new GCM push notification. I have successfully integrated the GCMIntentService class which extends GCMBaseIntentService.  When I send the push notification from server using PHP, the GCM sends the message data as a JSON object.  I am using the following code in my Android GCM service, and its returning a null value with the new code.

```
public void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();     
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action))   {            
             message=intent.getStringExtra("message");                                  
            createNotification(context);
        }
   }
```

The PHP Script contains :

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

```
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
```

Please suggest me what all the changes I require in my PHP script to send the push notification using GCM libraries and without JSON.

Thanks in advance
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to send the payload via JSON - whats the reason you do not want to use JSON?

Comment: Just wanted to confirm whether we can use only JSON to send the data with the push message.

Comment: no it has to be encapsulated with JSON - and to be precise only json with String parameters ( because of backwards compatibility to 2.2 )

Comment: Thank you. I have done the code to parse JSON and it is working fine from my Applicaiton :)

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed send payload without JSON (if you preferred), just like C2DM.

First, the content type is changed to this:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

Then your HTTP body will contain this:

```
registration_id=xxxxxx&collapse_key=yyyyy&data.data1=value1&data.data2=value2
```

HOWEVER, by sending payload as plain text you can only send it to `one device at a time`. This reason alone should make you avoid using this option, unless you already have bulk-sending logic in your C2DM code that you don't wish to change.

See here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#request