# Compulsory to use JSON form of request in Google GCM?

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I am migrating from google C2DM to GCM using Java.
I read this post [GCM Push Notification without using JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577033/gcm-push-notification-without-using-json). Even on google docs I found that plain-text or UTF-8 content-type is allowed. I am using API key for browser apps and also tried curl command. Every time I am getting response code 401 which is related to authorization. Below is the URL I am forming:

```
Collapse_key=0&Auth_Token=

> my api key for browser apps

&data.payload=

> meesage to be send

&registration_id=

> id of registered device
```

May I know the reason and solution for response code 401 ?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 401 occurred when API key is not valid. For details check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#auth_error).

You should send data as a json format. The format is shown below. It is explained in details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#request).

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried again using curl and it returns json data. It has success:1 but still from my J2EE application I am getting response code 401. what could be the reason ?

Comment: The format of my request is `https://andoid.googleapis.com/gcm/send?collapse_key=0&Auth_Token="api key"&data.payload="message to be send"&registration_id="id of registered device"` And in header a content-type, content-length and authorization: key is there.

Comment: collapse_key should be type of string.

Comment: What should be the request method - GET or POST ? I've used POST.

Comment: Check the request format here : http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#request

Comment: I checked it from this URL so many times. This is the exception I am getting `java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send?`. I am testing it from outside corporate firewall.

Comment: Ok but I am sending it in UTF-8 format and don't want to use JSON as the code for C2DM is available. So just changing the required part for migration to GCM.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json for JSON; application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.` So I am using charset=UTF-8 and my API key is valid. why I am getting response code 401 ?

Comment: Both api keys are valid from curl but when I send the request from java code either in UTF-8 or JSON, every time I get response code 401.

Comment: Should I pass Auth_Token="api key" in UTF-8 request ?

Comment: You should add Authorization:key=YOUR_API_KEY into the HTTP Header.

Comment: `url = new URL(aggrURL);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new CustomizedHostnameVerifier());
            huc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            huc.setDoOutput(true);
            huc.setUseCaches(false);
            huc.setRequestMethod("POST");
            huc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type:","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");            
            huc.setRequestProperty("Authorization: key=", "my_api_key");` - this is my java code

Comment: Getting response code 401 from standalone java program with static values of sender id and API key.